# NG01203: No value accessor for form control name for mat-radio-group

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material2

Unit test is failed saying **Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name : 'gender'**  . I have used NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR but still same . I am using Reactive form and the HTML code is

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option"  class="w-48" id="gender" name="gender" formControlName="gender" >
            <mat-radio-button value="Male" name="male">Male</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="Female" name="female">Female</mat-radio-button>      
          </mat-radio-group>
```

WHat am I doing wrong here

```
     {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,  
          useExisting:  myComponent, 
          multi: true
        }
```